# None of code can establish http connection over BIS

Tags: blackberry, httpconnection

I am new in developing Blackberry Application.

In these three days, I already searched and learned in both forum and tutorial from the RIM itself. But none of them can solve my problem. >.<

So. I already tried some different methods to establish http connection over BIS in 4.6.

These are the following codes:
1. 
        HttpConnection httpConnection;

```
    String url = "myURL;deviceside=true";

    try{
    httpConnection = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
    Dialog.inform(">.<");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Dialog.inform(e.getMessage());
    }
```

From the code #1 above, none of the dialogs are displayed.

1. ```
   String url = "myURL";


   try {

       StreamConnection s = (StreamConnection)Connector.open(url);

       InputStream input = s.openInputStream();

       Dialog.inform("sblm byte");

       byte[] data = new byte[256];
       int len = 0;
       StringBuffer raw = new StringBuffer();

       Dialog.inform("stlh buat byte");

       while( -1 != (len = input.read(data))) {
           raw.append(new String(data, 0, len));
       }

       Dialog.inform("stlh while");
       response = raw.toString();
       Dialog.inform(response);

       input.close();
       s.close();

   } 

           catch(Exception e) { }
   ```

As well as code #1, this code above also doesnt pop up any dialog.

I am desperately need the right guide for establishing simple http connection. Is there any technique that I missed? Do I need any signature for this? Do I need extra setting in both my Blackberry device (BB 8900 with OS 5.00) or in my compiler, Eclipse?

Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know you need to be a RIM partner (costs money) in order to use BIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
 try {

    HttpConnection httpConnection=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
    httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
   if(httpConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
   {
     InputStream is=httpConnection.openInputStream();
     int ch;
     StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
       while((ch=is.read())!=-1)
       {
        buffer.append((char)ch);
      }
     }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception From Thread"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```