# How to arrange the MenuItems that we add in menu

Tags: blackberry, java-me, menuitem

I wrote a program that adds some options in the menu. It successfully added all the items that i inserted. Now i arranged all the items also. But the "switch application" option is still at the top. How can I change its position?

```
    MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("leave",0x00010004,0);

    addMenuItem(mi1);

    MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem("importrouteplan",0x00020005,0);
    addMenuItem(mi2);
    MenuItem mi4 = new MenuItem("get5daysplan",0x00020005,0);
    addMenuItem(mi4);
    MenuItem mi3 = new MenuItem("gettodaysplan",0x00020005,0);
    addMenuItem(mi3);
    MenuItem mi6 = new MenuItem("stoptracktime",0x00030006,0);  
    addMenuItem(mi6);
    MenuItem mi5 = new MenuItem("starttracktime",0x00030006,0);
    addMenuItem(mi5);
```

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you currently have and what you'd like to have. Do you mean the system menu item "Switch Application" is above your custom menu items? It sounds odd. I believe "Switch Application" should be below your items. Probably a sreenshot would clear the case.

Comment: you are right, it turns out it depends on OS level (check my answer for details).

Comment: Please post a comment while voting down my question so that i may not repeat the same mistake again. Because people like Vijay.jangid07 are acting like kids and vote down my question with personal grudges

Comment: Just for the record: I can confirm Vijay.jangid07 does act like a kid. P.S. Sorry for saying this and if this does not correspond to SO rules the moderator may feel free to kill this comment.

Comment: @Arhimed He particularly told me to wait until he gets a 150 reputation and the moment he got that reputation i got two of my questions vote down all of a sudden. What does this mean?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I have no info (I am not a moderator) to know what does that mean. However he threatened me and said a lot of black words in my address after I downvoted his totally wrong answer. Well, sometimes people downvote my answers and that's ok for me (they have right to do that if my answer is in any point bad), I am not acting like a kid in response.

Comment: I've made an observation this guy very frequenly gives poor quality answers. Some of his answers are a quick headless copy-pastes or just guesses which don't solve the asker issue. For instance, he is asked about BIS usage issue, but he replies how to make an http call in general without any specifics about BIS - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709669/none-of-code-can-establish-http-connection-over-bis/7711479#7711479. Or this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845088/how-to-find-application-size-in-blackberry-by-code/7845280#7845280 . Or his reply on your current question.

Comment: I think so. Today i got five of my questions vote down. It never happened to me like this.Is there a way to know who has vote down my questions or answers

Comment: Could you point me to the place where "He particularly told me to wait until he gets a 150 reputation"? Probably we could attract moderator attention to this. Because this smells like a dishonest game.

Comment: The story goes on.. on Friday and today I got downvotes for my 12 old questions/answers without any explanation. Right before this happened the person whom we suspect changed his name to http://stackoverflow.com/users/958670/bb-expert (probably to protect his real identity) because he understands he's doing wrong things. I've never thought I'll be a victim of revenge downvotes just because of my honest behaviour.

Comment: Can't we do anything to stop this?

Comment: @Arhimed Sorry for everything....

Comment: @Pramod Sorry for everything...

Comment: @BB Expert: Vijay, for me this is already in the past, so I don't feel myself offended any longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out it depends on OS level.

For instance, on OS 4.7 "Switch Application" is always in the bottom section near the "Close". However if you open any native BB app in OS 6 simulator, then you'll see RIM changed the this behaviour - "Switch Application" is always in the top section while they left "Close" in the bottom.

So basically your code is fully Ok as is and you don't need to change it. However if you do need to put any item above the "Switch Application", then you can do it by using the same top-most ordinal:

```
new MyMenuItem("Above Switch Application", 0 /*ordinal*/, 0);
```

Note despite in this case "Above Switch Application" IS above the "Switch Application", it shares the same ordinal group (0) so there will be no separator between the two (which I guess in not acceptable for the majority of the cases).

Comment: how to add separator above "Switch Application" in OS 6. in my application separator is working in all screen in os 6. but one screen have "Browserfield" so "Select" option is placed in menu. and it is not working in that scren. so give me some suggetion.

Comment: @Coder: Please ask a separate/standalone question for your case providing detailed description (screenshots would be also nice).

Answer (score 0):

```
MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem("leave",0x00010004,0);
```

The last argument in MenuItem is for Priority in the Menu.

So don't pass it as 0.

The priority of the menu item.
A lower value indicates a higher priority, 
conversely a higher value indicates a lower priority.

Change the priority and try.

Comment: Now i gave priority as 6 to all the items. Still the output is same